# Access variable of Viewcontroller in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, appdelegate, starscream

As the question says, I am trying to access a variable of my ViewController inside my AppDelegate.swift.

in `func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication){}`, I want to access a WebSocket object inside my ViewController and do socket.disconnect(), so that the socket is disconnecting when my application is going to get shut downed.

I already searched the net for quite a bit but nothing seemed to help me in this situation.

Comment: how do you present the viewController that you want to access? are there any navigationControllers, or are they just presented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add an observer in your view controller:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
      selector: #selector(applicationWillTerminate),
      name: .UIApplicationWillTerminate,
      object: nil)
```

using callback:

```
@objc func applicationWillTerminate() {
    // Disconnect socket

}
```

Also I think everything will be disconnected when app terminates

Comment: It kind of gets disconnect but when i just terminate the app, an error occures on my server endpoint. I just want a clean disconnect upon App termination.

Comment: Never mind now, the problem seems to lie with my wsserver and not the client. Your solution is right.